# android command line shell

Tags: shell, terminal, command-line

I have a Nokia X running Android 4.4.4 and I have Terminal Emulator and Busybox 1.24 installed but I can't still find some useful commands to perform several operations with the command line interface.That's my question:what's the best and the most complete shell utilities to install? Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking **app recommendations, device recommendations, or other purchasing advice** are off-topic as they become obsolete quickly. [Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/45122/edit).

Comment: Recommended reading: our [command-line tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/command-line/info) :)

Answer (score 0):

The only other one I know of is ToyBox.

http://www.landley.net/toybox/about.html

Answer (score -1):

The best is a combination of 3 commands, which are `cd`, `ls` and `cat`.

You start with `cd /`, followed by `ls -l`

You detect a thing called `mnt`

Do `cd mnt`, followed by `ls -l`

Do `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Go to `/sdcard/pers`. There's so much explore.